# Reading hexadecimal Unicode String from file and turn it into Java String?

Tags: java, utf-8, utf

I am writing currently a little parser for JSON documents. 
UTF characters can be represented as `\u0628`.

How can I turn the string `\u0628` into a real Java character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a piece of code like this:

```
String str = myString.split(" ")[0];
str = str.replace("\\","");
String[] arr = str.split("u");
String text = "";
for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
    int hexVal = Integer.parseInt(arr[i], 16);
    text += (char)hexVal;
}
```

or you can use  Apache Commons Lang:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

@Test
public void testUnescapeJava() {
    String sJava="\\u0048\\u0065\\u006C\\u006C\\u006F";
    System.out.println("StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(sJava):\n" + StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(sJava));
}


 output:
 StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(sJava):
 Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the bytes using the `UTF_16` charset:

E.g.

```
byte[] data = {0x06, 0x28};
String string = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
```

You could find the escapes using a regex

```
private static Pattern ESCAPE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{2})([0-9a-fA-F]{2})");

public static String replaceCharEscapes(String input) {
    Matcher m = ESCAPE_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    if (!m.find()) {
        return input;
    }
    StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder(input.subSequence(0, m.start()));
    int lastEnd = m.end();
    outputBuilder.append(getChar(m));

    while (m.find()) {
        outputBuilder.append(input.subSequence(lastEnd, m.start()))
                .append(getChar(m));
        lastEnd = m.end();
    }

    if (lastEnd != input.length()) {
        outputBuilder.append(input.subSequence(lastEnd, input.length()));
    }

    return outputBuilder.toString();
}

private static String getChar(Matcher m) {
    return new String(new byte[] {
        Byte.parseByte(m.group(1), 16),
        Byte.parseByte(m.group(2), 16),
    });
}
```

example:

```
replaceCharEscapes("\\u0043:\\\\u0050\\u0072\\u006f\\u0067\\u0072\\u0061\\u006ds")
```

returns `C:\Programs`